# Submit button in boostrap modal doesn't submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an mvc generated form (@Html.BeginForm()) with button of type="submit" within bootstrap modal overlay.

```
<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" type="submit">Close</button>
```

When I click the button - all it does is closes the modal.
Submit action (POST to the controller) is not performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to remove the `data-dismiss="modal"` property since that triggers the `Modal` to close instead of doing a submit.

Answer (score 0):

simply add `<input type="submit" value="Close" class="btn" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
do this

@using(@html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName"))
{
<input type="submit" value="Close" class="btn" />
}
```